# Spring boot 3 hibernate 6 Querydsl Gradle Unable to load class 'jakarta.persistence.Entity'

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, build.gradle, querydsl

I have project with `spring-boot:3.1.4` and `query-dsl:5.0.0`
`build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.4'
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:5.0.0:jakarta'
    implementation 'com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:5.0.0:jakarta'
    annotationProcessor 'com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:5.0.0:jakarta'
}
```

When I tried to build project, this error happened.
Here is the build log

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/persistence/Entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a dependency.

Try to add this to your dependencies

```
annotationProcessor 'jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:3.1.0'
```